# Will declaring a metapackage dependency pull all children packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have meta package structured like so

```
catkin_ws/src/vision_common/

  vision_common/ (a subpackage in the package)

  vision_msgs/

  vision_3d/
```

I want to use the vision_msgs in another package. Is it sufficient to do `<run_depend>vision_common</run_depend>`and

```
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  vision_msgs
)
```

In the other package? I'm running into trouble with the following error:

```
CMake Error at /home/vision/catkin_ws/build/planning_common/cmake/planning_common-genmsg.cmake:3 (message):
  Could not find messages which
  '/home/vision/catkin_ws/src/planning_common/srv/SimplePlanningSrv.srv'
  depends on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

  Cannot locate message [ParametricObjectMsg]: unknown package
  [vision_common] on search path [{{'household_objects_database_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/household_objects_database_msgs/msg'],
  'shape_msgs': ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/shape_msgs/msg'], 'vision_msgs':
  ['/home/vision/catkin_ws/src/vision_common/vision_msgs/msg'],
  'std_msgs': ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/std_msgs/msg'], 'moveit_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/moveit_msgs/msg'], 'trajectory_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/trajectory_msgs/msg'], 'sensor_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/sensor_msgs/msg'], 'object_recognition_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/object_recognition_msgs/msg'], 'octomap_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/octomap_msgs/msg'], 'manipulation_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/manipulation_msgs/msg'], 'geometry_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/geometry_msgs/msg'], 'actionlib_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/actionlib_msgs/msg'], 'control_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/control_msgs/msg'], 'diagnostic_msgs':
  ['/opt/ros/groovy/share/diagnostic_msgs/msg']}}]
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:280 (include)
  planning_common/CMakeLists.txt:28 (generate_messages)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73747/will-declaring-a-metapackage-dependency-pull-all-children-packages./) by [ehuang](https://answers.ros.org/users/6034/ehuang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; you should explicitly depend on the packages that you use.

The main reason for this is that the CMake file in most metapackages does not pull in cmake files for its dependencies.

In your case, I would explicitly depend on vision_msgs in both your package.xml and your CMake file.

P.S. - this may also be a problem with your service file. If you're still having trouble, I suggest adding your service file to the question.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2